# Кинематика(Python)

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть кинект от xbox, который постоянно считывает мое положение на плоскости xyz, также у меня есть робот с мотором, который должен поворачивать мотор в зависимости от положения моей руки, соответственно это будет какая-то переменная которая будет задавать скорость мотора и как-то высчитываться, вот у меня вопрос, каким образом можно рассчитать. У меня в цикле перебирается y в зависимости от того где сейчас рука, у принимает постоянно разные значения, в зависимости от которых мотор должен поворачиваться на определенный градус. Как я понял данный вопрос связан с прямой/обратной кинематикой, но вообще не разобрался что к чему. Расстояние от захвата до самого нижнего положения примерно 20 см, какую формулу надо использоваться для того чтобы посчитать градус поворота мотора в зависимости от положения руки. Ниже приведен код в котором идет обработка позиций руки(x,y,z) использую я только y в данный момент

```
    def draw_skeleton_data(pSkelton, index, positions, width = 4):
    start = pSkelton.SkeletonPositions[positions[0]]
    for position in itertools.islice(positions, 1, None): 
    next = pSkelton.SkeletonPositions[position.value]
    curstart = skeleton_to_depth_image(start, dispInfo.current_w, 
    dispInfo.current_h) 
    curend = skeleton_to_depth_image(next, dispInfo.current_w, 
    dispInfo.current_h)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, SKELETON_COLORS[index], curstart, curend, 
    width)
    start = next
    # start_list = str(start) 
x=start.x
y=start.y
print(y)
z=start.z
w=start.w
if y > 0 and y < 0.1:
    sent = sock.sendto( m0, server_address)
elif y < 0:
    sent = sock.sendto( m1, server_address)
elif y > 0.1:
    sent = sock.sendto( m2, server_address)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите свой код, люди здесь не любят вопросы типа: "что -то не работает, но кода нет".

Comment: Добавил, но по факту данный код ничего не дает, мне нужна формула с помощью которой я смогу привести значение y в угол поворота мотора

Comment: наверное тут подойдёт формула круга x ** 2+y ** 2=r ** 2   . r знаем, х знаем. у вычисляем.

Comment: Причем тут круг?) Добавил фотографию руки чтобы было понятнее. Как мне подсказали, скорее всего должен быть синус и арксинус

Comment: У меня треугольник получается, но явно не круг

Comment: (там не умножение а степень. х и у надо брать и с минусовыми значениями и патом сдвигать.) для расчёта угла руки действительно не подходит.сбила картинка, извините.

Comment: Да, ничего. Должна получиться функция от координаты(у) руки, которую видит кинект, возвращающая альфу

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha = arcsin(ym /  L)
```

где `ym` - расстояние по вертикали от оси, L - длина руки

На всякий случай - угол будет в радианах, при необходимости его можно перевести в градусы.

Comment: Так, это просто альфа самого робота, а каким образом можно сделать так чтобы это все было связанно? Соответственно чтобы в зависимости от того где моя рука находиться(y От -0.5 до 0.5), там и угол поворота мотора, как я понимаю будет другая формула использоваться, верно? @MBo

Comment: Соответственно чтобы дельта руки, равнялась дельте мотора, как на рисунке и чтобы это все было синхронизировано

Comment: Точнее не чтобы, а так и есть, дельта руки пропорциональна дельте мотора, только как это все синхронизировать

Comment: Если вычесть текущий угол манипулятора из угла руки, получим угол, на который нужно переместиться

Comment: А в плане кода, как это реализовать?)) Какие формулы нужно использовать? @MBo

Comment: формула для нахождения угла уже дана, про разность углов, наверное, всё должно быть понятно